# Wireshark - how to merge packets of Data of a bin file which was sent over the LAN?

Tags: wireshark

I tried to send a ~80k dat file over the LAN from one device to another and then combine the captured packets back to the original file, for testing and learning purposes.
I couldn't find any way to automatically do that. I did manage to copy all the data parts manually as Hex stream (see second screenshot) and combine them into one long Hex string and then convert it to dat using https://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_file.php?lang=en, which worked, but how do I do it automatically with Wireshark, or at least merge all the data (excluding the packet headers of course, the first 20+16 bytes) into 1 Hex file?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is just select Analyze -> Follow -> TCP Stream, that will open a window where you can see the data exchanged by both sides, select only one sense of the communication, different ways of showing the data and even saving it to a file.